# Connect to Bitbucket database from Bitbucket plugin

Tags: bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have an instance of Bitbucket which has an Oracle database. I am creating a plugin where I need to use the database tables directly (not the AO tables). Is there any way to achive this?

Do I need to use a normal JPA framework inside the plugin to fetch the details? If yes, how do I get the database credentials from the APIs without the need to store them inside the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I work on Bitbucket and would love to help find a solution that isn't as scary, dangerous and unsupported as your one sounds :)

Comment: I need to retrieve all the project permissions and repo level permissions for a user. I don't see an API call to do that. So I need to access the database tables (user, project, repository) to fetch these details.

Comment: Ah. Yes, this isn't something the API provides easily.
It's not something on our short term roadmap, but you can watch https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-7346 and https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3894 for updates.